# C++ threads. Why always executes last thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Why only last threads executes every time? I'm trying to divide grid into N workers, half of grid always not touchable and other part always proceed by 1 last created thread. Should I use an array instead of vector? Locks also do not help to resolve this problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <future>
#include <thread> 
#include <pthread.h>

#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

std::mutex m;

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

  int iterations = atoi(argv[1]), workers = atoi(argv[2]), x = atoi(argv[3]), y = atoi(argv[4]);

  vector<vector<int> > grid( x , vector<int> (y, 0));
  std::vector<thread> threads(workers);

  int start, end, lastworker, nwork;

  int chunkSize = y/workers;

  for(int t = 0; t < workers; t++){

    start = t * chunkSize;
    end = start + chunkSize;

    nwork = t;

    lastworker = workers - 1;

    if(lastworker == t){
      end = y; nwork = workers - 1;
    }

threads[nwork] = thread([&start, &end, &x, &grid, &t, &nwork, &threads] {

                cout << " ENTER TO THREAD -> " << threads[nwork].get_id() << endl;

    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j)
                    {
                      grid[i][j] = t;

                    }              
                }

                sleep(2);
        });
cout << threads[nwork].get_id() << endl;

}

for(auto& th : threads){
 th.join();
}

    for (int i = 0; i < y; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < x; ++j)
        {
          cout << grid[i][j];

        }
        cout << endl;
    } 

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: What arguments are you expecting?  I'm getting segfaults with `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Try 1 2 4 4 or 1 4 16 16

Comment: The second one is number of workers, the last 2 is a x/y of the grid

Comment: Both of those patterns still make asan complain.  Have you run your code using valgrind or asan?

Comment: I'm running this code via mac os console. In the correct directory - ./test 1 2 4 4, for me in works fine.

Comment: Compiled with g++ test.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread -o test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[&start, &end, &x, &grid, &t, &nwork, &threads]
```

This line is the root of the problem. You are capturing all the variables by reference, which is not what you want to do.

As a consequence, each thread uses the same variables, which is also not what you want.

You should only capture `grid` and `threads` by reference, the other variables should be captured by value ('copied' into the lambda)

```
[start, end, x, &grid, t, nwork, &threads]
```

Also, you are accessing `grid` wrong everywhere: change `grid[i][j]` to `grid[j][i]`

Comment: Thank you! Now it works fine. I should learn more about references and lambda.

Comment: You're welcome :) I recommend Jason Turner's youtube channel

Comment: Just checked with this code, it's seems that all this workers do not work simultaneously. With each new worker calculation time almost doubles... Can you help me?

Comment: You can post another question with fixed code. The reason you don't have better results may be that threads have overhead and a single thread may be more efficient if the work is small enough. Another reason may be false sharing. But that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
thread([&start, &end, &x, &grid, &t, &nwork, &threads] {
                                     =======
```

The lambda closure that gets executed by every thread captures a ***reference*** to `nwork`.

Which means that as the `for` loop iterates and starts every thread, each captured thread will always reference the ***current*** value of `nwork`, at the time it does.

As such, the outer loop probably quickly finishes creating each thread object before all the threads actually initialize and actually enter the lambda closure, and each closure sees the same value of `nwork`, because it is captured ***by reference***, which is the last thread id.

You need to capture `nwork` ***by value*** instead of by reference.

Comment: Just checked with this code, it's seems that all this workers do not work simultaneously. With each new worker calculation time almost doubles... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing all the thread parameters are references to the thread lambda. However, when the loop continues in the main thread, the thread parameter variables change, which changes their values in the *threads* as well, messing up all the previously-created threads.